# Process list with Dataframe Typ

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I create a list and fill it with data from text files:

```
indir = "..."
infiles = [os.path.join(indir, f) for f in os.listdir(indir) if f.endswith('.txt')]

dataframes = []
for f in infiles:
    dataframes.append(pd.read_csv(f,sep='\t',skiprows=21,header=None))
```

and it looks like that:

[image: dataframes - List]

Now I would like to process the data in the DataFrame matrix. E.g. to interpolate or maybe delete a column.

How could I implement this?
Thanks a lot for the answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets consider what your code does: you are appending objects of type `pandas.DataFrame` to a python list `dataframes`, therefore if you want to work with the dataframes inside the list you should iterate through it. For example if you want to work with a selection of the first 10 columns of every DataFrame you could use the following code:

```
selection = range(10)
for df in dataframes:
   smaller_df = df[selection]
   # Do whatever you want with smaller_df
```

I suggest you read the pandas guide for [indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html) as working with dataframes can be a bit tricky.